Stable gap-less packing of a box with boxes
define a box packing as gap-less if

all inner boxes have disjoint interior
the sum of volumes of the inner box equals that of the outer box
the sum of the extents of the inner boxes in each principal direction equals that of the outer box

define a box paxking as stable if

for every hyperplane with a point inside the outer box there is an inner box with inner points to both sides of that hyperplane.

Questions:


for which $k$, depending on dimension $n$ of the boxes do stable gap-less packings of boxes with boxes exist?
how can such packings be found, given $k$ and $n$?


In $2{-}d$ there are many examples from squaring the square which is a very special case of this question for $n=2$; this question allows boxes of equal size and arbitrary extents in each principal direction.


What is $k$ in thefirst question? 2) What is a box —-a parallelepiped or a cube? 3) What is extent?


$k$ is the number of smaller boxes that are to be packed in a single bigger box; a box is the Cartesian product of $n$ intervals, one for each coordinate. Extent is the set of interval-lengths; in 3D aka length,width and height.

But then, the sum of extents of the inner boxes in one direction should be larger than the extent of the outer box, except for the trivial cases…

@IlyaBogdanov what does "but them" refer to? Have a look at the suaring the square.illustration on the wikipedia page; the sum of inner extents equals the outer extents. We are consudering mathematical abstractions of boxes, not physical objects
